# Please explain : "at least 95% of the time, the error does not exceed the reciprocal of the square root of the number of trials"

Tags: probability-theory

I am studying "Introduction to Probability" book by Charles M. Grinstead &  J. Laurie Snell and the authors give a rule of thumb to arrive at the number of trials needed in a probability experiment. It goes like

> "We shall see later that in these types of experiments [i.e., probability experiments], a rough rule of thumb is that, at least 95% of the time, the error does not exceed the reciprocal of the square root of the number of trials." (page 4)

I do not understand this line. How do we arrive at the number of trials using this thumb rule? Can you kindly give some examples to make it clearer to me? Thanks.

Comment: If you want an error of at most $\alpha$ (except with small probability, $5\%$), then with this rule of thumb you make $N\geq 1/\alpha^2$ trials (so that $1/\sqrt{N}\leq \alpha$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For concreteness, assume that we have a biased coin that has unknown probability of landing "heads" and we want to give a $95\%$ confidence interval for $p$.

Rrepeat the experiment of tossing the coin $n$ times. Let $\bar{X}$ be the sample proportion of heads. We will use $\bar{X}$ to estimate $p$.

Note that $\bar{X}$ has mean $p$ and variance $\frac{p(1-p)}{n}$. The function $p(1-p)$ attains a maximum of $\frac{1}{4}$ at $p=\frac{1}{2}$. So the variance of $\bar{X}$ is $\le \frac{1}{4n}$, and therefore $\bar{X}$ has standard deviation $\le \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$.

We assume that $n$ is large enough that the normal approximation can be used. Note that if $Z$ is standard normal, then $\Pr(|Z|\le 1.96)\approx 0.95$.

It follows that with probability at least $0.95$ we have
$$|\bar{X}-p| \le \frac{1.96}{2\sqrt{n}}\approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},$$
which is whaat we wanted to justify.